# How to create an empty JsResult in play json?

Tags: scala, play-json

I am writing an implicit reads returning `JsResult[Seq[T]]` based on a condition:

```
some_condition match{
     case Some(value) => // JsResult[Seq[T]]
     case _ => // returning an empty JsResult here of similar type?
}
```

What would be the way for return such `JsResult`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use the method [`validate`](https://github.com/playframework/play-json/blob/master/play-json/shared/src/main/scala/play/api/libs/json/JsReadable.scala#L37), which returns [`JsResult`](https://github.com/playframework/play-json/blob/master/play-json/shared/src/main/scala/play/api/libs/json/JsResult.scala#L202). There are 2 case classes that inherits `JsResult`:

1. [`JsSuccess`](https://github.com/playframework/play-json/blob/master/play-json/shared/src/main/scala/play/api/libs/json/JsResult.scala#L12)
2. [`JsError`](https://github.com/playframework/play-json/blob/master/play-json/shared/src/main/scala/play/api/libs/json/JsResult.scala#L52)

Therefore you can consider the following example:

```
case class T()
implicit val reads = Json.reads[T]
val jsValue: JsValue = ...

jsValue.validate[Seq[T]] match {
  case JsSuccess(t, path) =>
    println(t)
  case JsError(errors) =>
    println(errors)
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Tomer Shetah, it did brought the solution, went with an empty seq of JsSuccess

Comment: If you have a look at the [documentation](https://javadoc.io/doc/com.typesafe.play/play-json_2.13/latest/play/api/libs/json/Reads.html), you would find many combinator to transform a result according condition (`.filter`, `.collect`, `.andThen`, `.flatMapResult`, ...)